# React native - dependency graph struck while running release.apk file but works fine for debug.apk file

Tags: react-native

I have created a simple app which has a login page and clicks on login button it redirects to the second page and works fine when I execute the "react-native run-android" command. I have created .apk of it. When I execute the "react-native run-android --variant=release" command dependency are not loading. I did not get when I went wrong.

I am using third party libraries, are those giving errors?

```
"aws-sdk": "^2.395.0",
    "link": "^0.1.5",
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "^0.58.3",
    "react-native-aws3": "0.0.8",
    "react-native-device-info": "^0.26.2",
    "react-native-file-upload": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.28.0",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.6",
    "uniqid": "^5.0.3"
```

Can anyone please assist me to resolve this?

[image]

Comment: did u try to set keystore file? 
try in android studio

Comment: Set keystore file means? I did not get it properly.

Comment: To create .apk file I have followed the official document only.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android

Comment: Thank you. : ) . It worked for me.

Comment: Please don't add things like `[CLOSED]` to a question title. Either answer your own question with the solution and accept it after the timeout, or **delete** your question.

Comment: Sure. Thank you for suggesting.